Seen by feature on a Facebook group
I am an admin on a Facebook group but I can’t see the see the people who have seen the post. The other admin can and other members can but I can’t. The seen by is present and in bold but when I click on it, it shows nothing. The group has less than 250 members. How can I fix this?

Can you [edit] your post and add a screenshot illustrating the issue?
